# Javascript library that creates Custom QR Codes with a logo in the middle?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I would like to create a custom qr code with javascript that contains a logo in the middle.

I already found this project on github:
https://github.com/kaarposoft/qrlogo
but unfortunately this script creates 1000 qr codes, whereupon the logo is always positioned differently, apart from that this project is not really easy to handle. (no documentation etc). I have rewritten in such a way that only one qr code is generated and not more than one and also that it uses an img tag instead of waiting for an upload. Nevertheless, this is not optimal because the logo is always randomly on the qr code and it is a project and not a library.

So I would like to know if someone knows a library or has programmed something to generate a qr code with javascript from an img tag and a string.

Many greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just published [`<qr-code>`](https://github.com/bitjson/qr-code), A no-framework, no-dependencies, customizable, animate-able, SVG-based QR code web component.

It lets you customize the colors of the QR code, add an image in the center, and even add custom animations:

[image: animated, stylized QR code]

You can experiment with the demo in your browser here: https://qr.bitjson.com/

Comment: Oh nice I'm already a huge fan and can't wait to test it - I give it a try later! Also that you used StencilJS for that is more than pleasing. Well done!

Comment: I love it! Can't get to make it work with SvelteKit though :(

Answer (score 5):

[qrcode-with-logos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-with-logos) does the trick for me. I also came across [easyqrcodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyqrcodejs) which has a lot of extra features, though I have not yet used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I've used https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling and it works flawlessly with the support of the following options:

[image]

JSON Options:

```json
{
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "data": "https://qr-code-styling.com",
  "margin": 0,
  "qrOptions": {
    "typeNumber": "0",
    "mode": "Byte",
    "errorCorrectionLevel": "Q"
  },
  "imageOptions": { "hideBackgroundDots": true, "imageSize": 0.4, "margin": 0 },
  "dotsOptions": { "type": "extra-rounded", "color": "#6a1a4c" },
  "backgroundOptions": { "color": "#ffffff" },
  "image": "10cc19bd484118dbcd0a7886a38ceddc.png",
  "dotsOptionsHelper": {
    "colorType": { "single": true, "gradient": false },
    "gradient": {
      "linear": true,
      "radial": false,
      "color1": "#6a1a4c",
      "color2": "#6a1a4c",
      "rotation": "0"
    }
  },
  "cornersSquareOptions": { "type": "extra-rounded", "color": "#000000" },
  "cornersSquareOptionsHelper": {
    "colorType": { "single": true, "gradient": false },
    "gradient": {
      "linear": true,
      "radial": false,
      "color1": "#000000",
      "color2": "#000000",
      "rotation": "0"
    }
  },
  "cornersDotOptions": { "type": "", "color": "#000000" },
  "cornersDotOptionsHelper": {
    "colorType": { "single": true, "gradient": false },
    "gradient": {
      "linear": true,
      "radial": false,
      "color1": "#000000",
      "color2": "#000000",
      "rotation": "0"
    }
  },
  "backgroundOptionsHelper": {
    "colorType": { "single": true, "gradient": false },
    "gradient": {
      "linear": true,
      "radial": false,
      "color1": "#ffffff",
      "color2": "#ffffff",
      "rotation": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Checkout the Zebra Crossing project.
It has ports to many languajes, including javascript.

[zxing project on GitHub](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)